# Get Class Type using typeof if Class has generic arguement

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a class:

```
public class test<T> {}
```

I would like to get the type of the class. I have the generic type. I need to use typeof.

would this work?

```
Type genericType = typeof(System.Int32);
typeof(test<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { genericType })
```

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Yes I did. I am actually using this in reflection but I'm not 100% sure that it is working correctly. The original issue is actually with a generic interface. The question is: Is that the correct way of getting the type?

Comment: ... Then what's the question... since what you have tried works for what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would this work?

Yes (assuming you add the proper semi-colon at the end of your line, and assign the resulting value to a `System.Type` variable).

For example, given:

```
Type genericType = typeof(System.Int32);
Type fullType = typeof(test<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { genericType });
Console.WriteLine(fullType);
```

This will print:

```
MyNamespace.test`1[System.Int32]
```

Which is the proper type name for the fully qualified type.

Comment: The reason I asked the question is because I am seeing something like:MyNamespace.test`1[[System.Int32]].